# Javascript wich loads images after load web page

Tags: php, javascript

my project is in wordpress. In my home page number of images are load from itunes store. It takes to long time n page loading.

May i have any javascript so that all the images are load after the load web page.

Answer (score 2):

It is done by a technique called Lazy Loading.

From Wikipedia:

> **Lazy loading** is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is needed. It can contribute to efficiency in the program's operation if properly and appropriately used. The opposite of lazy loading is eager loading.

You have a jQuery Plugin for Lazy Loading too! Check out [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

From their website:

> Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport (visible part of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them. This is opposite of image preloading.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin called [`lazyload`](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)